# Using resources after deployment on javafx using maven

Tags: maven, javafx, javafx-8, maven-plugin

I am struggling a bit using resources. I have a javafx maven Project. 
On one of my classes, I load a xml file, so I need to provide the route to it. 
My xml file is under /src/main/resources/files/Settings.xml . 
I am able to load it through this:

```
File f = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("files/Settings.xml").getFile());
```

I can execute it using jfx:run on enclipse an so far so good. Problem is, I want to deploy this app using jfx:jar or jfx:native. I do it, but when I do there is a jar file generated and a lib folder containing all the libs needed but the folder /files containing my resource settings.xml is not created and furthermore, even if I create it manually  there is an exception caught because the files is not found ( The path that is looking for is not /files/settings.xml )

I want to deploay my app with a directory structure like this:

On the directory MyApp I would have my MyApp.jar file and the libs,files,and videos directories. The files directory will contain Settings.xml file.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

This is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>apps.toni.com</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
    <name>MyApp</name>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>toni.com</name>
    </organization>

    <properties>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <build>

        <finalName>MyApp</finalName>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.2</version>
                <configuration>

                    <mainClass>app.source.general.MainApp</mainClass>

                    <!-- only required if signing the jar file -->
                    <keyStoreAlias>example-user</keyStoreAlias>
                    <keyStorePassword>example-password</keyStorePassword>
                    <allPermissions>true</allPermissions>

                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <build>1.8</build>
                    <testsource>1.8</testsource>
                    <testbuild>1.8</testbuild>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/resources/videos</directory>
            </resource>

            <resource>
                <directory>src/resources/files</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>


    <dependencies>

        <!-- MigLayout -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
            <artifactId>miglayout-javafx</artifactId>
            <version>4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging  -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>

     <!--  HIBERNATE -->

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to get the resource as a file. You can get an input stream directly from the resource as follows:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream("files/Settings.xml");
```

and then you can just do whatever you need from there.

Comment: What you said works for a compiled jar which includes the directory mentioned. What I want is the executable jar and two folders, files and videos. I want the two directories along with the jar because I want to be possible to change the parameters in the settings.xml which the jar is loading when booting. The same with the video, I want to change the video is playing just replacing the video file inside videos folder. How can I reference files and videos paths???

Comment: Ah, OK, I understand now. The way I've always done this (I'm not sure if this is the best) is to check at startup if the required files exist in some fixed folder (relative to user.home), and if not extract default files on the fly from inside the jar file. That keeps deployment simple (one jar file) and makes it easy on the user if they completely hose their settings.xml file (just delete it to go back to the default). Would this work? If not, *if* you can ensure you deploy the folders along with the jar file, you could potentially parse out the url of the jar to determine the file names.